# How can I persistently overwrite an attribute initialized by Rack::Builder?

Tags: ruby, oauth, rack, omniauth

I am trying to use OmniAuth to handle the OAuth flow for a small-ish Sinatra app. I can get 37signals Oauth to work perfectly, however I'm trying to create a strategy for Freshbooks Oauth as well.

Unfortunately Freshbooks require OAuth requests to go to a user specific subdomain. I'm acquiring the subdomain as an input and I then need to persistently use the customer specific  site URL for all requests.

Here's what I've tried up to now. The problem is that the new site value doesn't persist past the first request.

There's to to be a simple way to achieve this but I'm stumped.

```
  #Here's the setup -
  def initialize(app, consumer_key, consumer_secret, subdomain='api')
    super(app, :freshbooks, consumer_key, consumer_secret,
               :site               => "https://"+subdomain+".freshbooks.com", 
               :signature_method   => 'PLAINTEXT',
               :request_token_path => "/oauth/oauth_request.php",
               :access_token_path  => "/oauth/oauth_access.php",
               :authorize_path     => "/oauth/oauth_authorize.php"
          )
  end


  def request_phase
    #Here's the overwrite -
    consumer.options[:site] = "https://"+request.env["rack.request.form_hash"]["subdomain"]+".freshbooks.com"
    request_token = consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => callback_url)
    (session[:oauth]||={})[name.to_sym] = {:callback_confirmed => request_token.callback_confirmed?, 
                                           :request_token => request_token.token, 
                                           :request_secret => request_token.secret}
    r = Rack::Response.new
    r.redirect request_token.authorize_url
    r.finish
  end
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I had to change :consumer from attr_reader to attr_accessor in the omniauth/oauth.rb to get the above to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a summary of what I did for anyone who comes across this via Google.

I didn't solve the problem in the way I asked it, instead I pushed the subdomain into the session and then I overwrite it whenever the site value needs to be used.

Here's the code:

```
  #Monkeypatching to inject user subdomain
  def request_phase
    #Subdomain is expected to be submitted as <input name="subdomain">
    session[:subdomain] = request.env["rack.request.form_hash"]["subdomain"]
    consumer.options[:site] = "https://"+session[:subdomain]+".freshbooks.com"
    super 
  end

  #Monkeypatching to inject subdomain again
  def callback_phase
    consumer.options[:site] = "https://"+session[:subdomain]+".freshbooks.com"
    super
  end
```

Note that you still have to set something as the site when it's initialised, otherwise you will get errors due to OAuth not using SSL to make the requests.

If you want to see the actual code I'm using it's at: https://github.com/joeharris76/omniauth I'll push the fork up to the main project once I've battle tested this solution a bit more.